# getElementsByClassName not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I wrote this script for a 5 star ratings system I made and it makes the stars light up as the user hovers over them, for example: if a user is hovered over the third star, that one shows the lit star image as well as the first two. The script works in all newer browsers except FireFox. I have racked my brain over this for a while and cannot figure out why its not working in firefox. Any help is appreciated. Also, I am only interested in responses about raw Javascript, not JQuery or any other framework. Thanks a bunch.

```
function btnSwap(){
var myBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btns');
for(i=0; i<myBtns.length; i++){
    var elem = document.getElementById(myBtns[i].id);
    elem.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
    elem.onmouseover = btnOver;
    elem.onmouseout = btnOut;
    function btnOver(){
        var lit = document.getElementById(this.id);
        if(lit.id == "rb1"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb2"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb3"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb4"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb5"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb4').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }

}

function btnOut(){
        var lit = document.getElementById(this.id);
        if(lit.id == "rb1"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb2"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb3"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb4"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb5"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb4').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get any console errors in Firefox?

Comment: And any difference if you set the `elem.onmouseover = btnOver;` _after_ you define the functions rather than before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the function declarations inside the `for` loop.

```
function btnSwap(){

    var myBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('btns');

    // begin loop
    for(i=0; i<myBtns.length; i++){
        var elem = document.getElementById(myBtns[i].id);
        elem.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        elem.onmouseover = btnOver;
        elem.onmouseout = btnOut;
    }

    // outside the loop.. now function declarations.

    function btnOver(){
        var lit = document.getElementById(this.id);
        if(lit.id == "rb1"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb2"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb3"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb4"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb5"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        document.getElementById('rb4').src = "images/"+"starOver.png";
        }

    }

    function btnOut(){
        var lit = document.getElementById(this.id);
        if(lit.id == "rb1"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb2"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb3"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb4"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }
        if(lit.id == "rb5"){
        lit.src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb1').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb2').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb3').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        document.getElementById('rb4').src = "images/"+"starNorm.png";
        }

    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

Firefox respects conditional code blocks which wrap function declarations. For example:

```
if (true) {
    function a() { return 1; }
} else {
    function a() { return 2; }
}
a(); // => Chrome: 2, Firefox: 1
```

Since a `for` code block might *not* be executed, Firefox tries to respect the conditional nature of the `for` loop. You can see this more directly in a `while (false)` loop.

```
while(false) {
    function a() { return 'a'; }
}
a(); // => Chrome: 'a', Firefox: Throws an error.
```

In Firefox, `a` is never defined because the condition never succeeds.

However, if there is a code block which will always be executed no matter the condition, the function definition *will* be hoisted. We can see this in a `do...while` loop.

```
var x = a;
do {
    function a() { return 'a'; }
} while(false);
x(); // => Both browsers: 'a'
```

No problem hoisting here because a `do...while` code block is always guaranteed to execute.

---

Also, is there a reason you're doing stuff like this?

```
var elem = document.getElementById(myBtns[i].id)
```

There's no need to get an element by id if you already have it. Just use

```
var elem = myBtns[i];
```

Comment: It does matter. Have you tried this in Firefox? `var x; for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { x = a; function a() { } }`  I have. Before I posted.

Comment: OK, I guess you're  right.  An actual function definition is hoisted to the top of the function per spec.  But an assignment of a function to a variable apparently is order-sensitive (your example works in Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox).  There is apparently some confusion in the implementations between function expression and function declaration which are treated differently.

Comment: Brilliant... Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help and info. Oh and the reason for this... document.getElementById(myBtns[i].id) is that I eat paint chips and rode the short bus to school. Also, im fairly new to Javascript so Im fumbling around a bit. Thanks for the help friend.

Comment: I changed it to var elem = myBtns[i]; and all is well

Comment: I apologize for the comment. It was out of line.